# faster way to downmix 5.1 videos to stereo?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a hand full of movies that are all in 5.1 audio, i need there to be one audio track that is only in stereo. i have found a few suggestions as to how to do this but some dont work for me and others are way too slow.

the one i found that works the fastest is this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy -map 0:a:0? -c:a:1 aac -ac 2 -metadata:s:a:1 title="Eng 2.0 Stereo" -map 0:a:1? -c:a:2 copy -map 0:a:2? -c:a:3 copy -map 0:a:3? -c:a:4 copy -map 0:a:4? -c:a:5 copy -map 0:a:5? -c:a:6 copy -map 0:a:6? -c:a:7 copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "output"
```

sadly i do not remember where it came from.

the problem with this being that it creates a separate audio track, and for my purposes this does not work.

doing just the standard -ac 2 works but is way to slow, i estimated to take over 40 hours to go through all my movies.

edit:
a bit of extra information to throw in here

- all the movies are mp4's
- all except 2 movies are 5.1 audio (there is 1 7.1 and 1 mono. i dont really care about them tho)
- the command i posted runs at about a 40x speed while just doing -ac 4 runs at 2x speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottleneck is the audio encoding.

Command can just be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 output.mp4
```

- Make sure your `ffmpeg` version 4.0 or newer or else encoding will be slower.

Using `-c:a libfdk_aac -afterburner 0` may be 2x faster:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 output.mp4
```

- Due to the license of libfdk_aac you need to [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) to use this encoder.

Not much else you can do.